# Where's the font file?

Tags: html, css, font-face

I'm building a page with this font, see here: [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/PSy3N/1/)

The font is called Cursive; it's not a web-safe font. On Chrome and Firefox, it looks great. However, in IE, it doesn't show.
I'd like to use a `@font-face` css declaration but I'm wondering where I can find the font file for it? I assume it's already loaded on my computer somewhere; I'd like to find the files I need to them on a server.

[image: Here is the image of what I'm seeing]

Comment: I did and the font is not listed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the fonts we are looking at could be completely different based on what fonts we have installed on our separate machines, why not try [What The Font](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)?

Take a screenshot of the text you see and upload it to Whatthefont -- it will detect what font it is using and give you several options to download both free and paid.

From there you can include it in your css file.

Comment: Ok, great link. However, it did not find the font.

Comment: Ok, very good, it was indeed a Comic Sans MS. Thanks for recognizing it.

Comment: Do I need an @font-face for this font? And if so, where are the font files? Thanks.

Comment: @frenchie [here](http://web.nickshanks.com/fonts/microsoft-core-web-fonts) is a download. Use the steps in my other answer to include it in a style sheet. [Although not everyone loves it...](http://comicsanscriminal.com/)

Comment: Ok, are these fonts for desktops (.exe extension)? Where are the font files for css @font-face?

Answer (score 1):

Your looking for the actual font file? There are literally hundreds of free font download sites within Google's grasp. [Here was my top result](http://www.fontspace.com/category/cursive).

Once you have found a file you like, ftp it to your server. Then using a css `@font-face` to include it in your stylesheet.

*The benefit of using a service like Googles font api is that it is free and fast - however, there is nothing stopping you from doing this from your own server and with your own file.*

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: "My Custom Font";
    src: url(http://www.example.org/mycustomfont.ttf) format("truetype");
}
p.customfont { 
    font-family: "My Custom Font", Verdana, Tahoma;
}
</style>
<p class="customfont">Hello world!</p>
```

[sample via hangy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11963/hangy)

Comment: No, the font on Chrome looks different; I'm not looking for a cursive font, I'm looking the files of the font called Cursive that I'm seeing  when I look at the page on jsfiddle in Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see it on my machine.  But is this the one you're looking for:

http://openfontlibrary.org/font/cursive

It looks like there is an open license, so you could run it through [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to get a nice `@font-face` declaration.

Comment: I'm not looking for a cursive font, I'm looking the files of the font called Cursive that I'm seeing  when I look at the page in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Fair enough @frenchie.  Although you did say you were looking for a font by the name Cursive.  Could you take a screen cap and add it to the question?  That might help.

Comment: I did, the screen shot is in the question's body. Now that I know the name of the font, I'm wondering if I need an @font-face for it and if I did, where are the files and are they free to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The font that your browser is rendering as 'Cursive' is nothing more than our old friend 'Comic Sans'.

[Comic Sans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_Sans)

["Cursive"](http://jsfiddle.net/PSy3N/4/)

Compare the two links to verify

Comment: Yes, it's Comic Sans; is this font free to use?